# Multiclass classification using Keras

Tags: classification, keras

I am trying to modify the keras examples for a three-class classification using vgg16 pretrained model. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import applications
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
img_width, img_height = 224, 224
top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data6/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data6/validation'
nb_train_samples = 300
nb_validation_samples = 60
epochs = 50
batch_size = 10
def save_bottlebeck_features():
   datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
   model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               train_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='categorical',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_train)

   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               validation_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='categorical',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_validation)

def train_top_model():
   train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
   train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // 3) + [1] *       (nb_train_samples // 3 + [2] * (nb_train_samples // 3)))
   validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'rb'))
   validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples // 3) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples // 3 + [2] * (nb_validation_samples // 3))
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
   model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
   sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
   model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
         loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
          model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)

save_bottlebeck_features()
train_top_model()
```

I'm getting an invalid syntax at the line: model = Sequential()
Kindly help me with the correction. Looking forward.

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis in the preceding line, which begins with `validation_labels`.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Also, I have to add the "to_categorical" statements to categorize using one hot encoding for multi-class classification problems. It works fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting code to make it compatible with tensorflow 2.0 and tf.keras.

```
from tf.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tf.keras.models import Sequential
from tf.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tf.keras import applications
from tf.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tf.keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
img_width, img_height = 224, 224
top_model_weights_path = 'bottleneck_fc_model.h5'
train_data_dir = 'data6/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data6/validation'
nb_train_samples = 300
nb_validation_samples = 60
epochs = 50
batch_size = 10
def save_bottlebeck_features():
   datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
   model = applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               train_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='categorical',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_train = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_train_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_train', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_train)

   generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
               validation_data_dir,
               target_size=(img_width, img_height),
               batch_size=batch_size,
               class_mode='categorical',
               shuffle=False)
   bottleneck_features_validation = model.predict_generator(
               generator, nb_validation_samples // batch_size)
   np.save(open('bottleneck_features_validation', 'wb'),bottleneck_features_validation)

def train_top_model():
   train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
   train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples // 3) + [1] *       (nb_train_samples // 3 + [2] * (nb_train_samples // 3)))
   validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy', 'rb'))
   validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples // 3) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples // 3 + [2] * (nb_validation_samples // 3)))
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Flatten(input_shape=train_data.shape[1:]))
   model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
   sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)
   model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
         loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   model.fit(train_data, train_labels,
          epochs=epochs,
          batch_size=batch_size,
   validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
          model.save_weights(top_model_weights_path)

save_bottlebeck_features()
train_top_model()
```